# Why is my document not saved in the firestore database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, user-data

Hi I have written the following class to save user data to firestore:

```
class UserDataService {
  static Future<String?> createUserRecord(
      String userID, String name, String email) async {
    try {
      await userCollection.doc(userID).set({
        userDataName: name,
        userDataEmail: email,
      });
      return createdRecordMessage;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

If I click on my register button the following code is executed that will call the method above:

```
 register(String? nameOfUser, String? emailOfUser, String? passwordOfUser,
      PropertyManagement? pm, BuildContext context) async {
    String? errorMessage = await widget.authService
        .registerWithEmailAndPassword(
            nameOfUser!.trim(), emailOfUser!.trim(), passwordOfUser!);

    if (errorMessage == signedInMessage) {
      errorMessage = await UserDataService.createUserRecord(
          widget.authService.currentUser()!.uid, nameOfUser, emailOfUser);

      if (errorMessage == createdRecordMessage) {
        errorMessage = await PropertyManagementDataService.createDatabaseRecord(
            pm!, widget.authService.currentUser()!);

        if (errorMessage == createdRecordMessage) {
          widget.authService.signOut();
          NavigationService.navigateToHome(context);
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    SnackbarService.displayWithTitleAndMessage(context, 'Error:', errorMessage);
  }
```

Can somebody tell why this dosen't work?

My security-rules on firebase aren't the problem.
And I also register the user before. So the auth state of the app is authenticated.

The strange thing is, that if I start my app an click the button the first time, just nothing happens.

When I click the button again the data is showing in the db.

**So I provided a video that shows the app during runtime.**
https://streamable.com/0rlkj5

1. There I try to create the user. Which works, but the firestore data isn't saved.
2. After that I delete the user in firebase while keeping my app open then click the register button again and then it works.

Why does this not work the first time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also when calling the method, the user data, the name, and the email are not null.

Comment: I think you are trying to update the existing document. One thing I noticed in your code is - you used .set() which replaces the existing document data. Instead of using that, you can use .update() function to update some fields in a document

Comment: And also please try to add little bit explanation about what actually happening after button click.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. set() would be ok because I try tor egister this user so there is no document in the db to update.
I also edited my question to show where and how the method is called

Comment: Also everything that happens after the line where I call the method to create the  user record won't be executed. But my programm is still running and there is no error thrown. I can use the app normaly. 
There is just nothing in firestore.

Comment: Since you are telling that code after `await UserDataService.createUserRecord` is not executing, one place to look into is `} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {`. Here, you don't have common else condition. So, I suggest you add simple else condition and check if you are getting some error there.

Comment: Thx, I tried to a catch FirebaseAuthException but there was nothing thrown.

Comment: Is it ok to use await on the set method? Or should I use .then() and .onError after the set() Method?

Comment: It feels like the await doesn't work

Comment: I now provided a video while the app is running. Maybe this helps to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it! After three days of work I realised that the firebase-team updated there web packages from version 8.4.1 to 8.6.1

This project was fairly new so I used 8.6.1 so I downgraded now to 8.4.1 and now it works just fine. So there is nothing wrong with my code instead there is a problem in Version 8.6.1.

I switched this:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js">
```

to this:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

So now I use a outdated version but it works. Hopefully they fix this.